# I want to change the image I am using whenever the product is added to cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this right now, need to add a condition in such a way that whenever the **getCartCount** is **0** it should show image as **bag_empty** instead of **bag** and when the **cart count** is more than **0** it should show **bag**

```
<Badge count={getCartCount()}>
  <img
   className="bag__img"
   src={bag}
   alt=""
   onClick={user ? handleOpenBag : handleDynamicLink}
   onMouseOver={() => setbag(hoverbag)}
   onMouseOut={() => setbag(cart)}
 />
</Badge>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **ternary operator** like below, assuming that you have your empty bag image in your public folder.

```js
<Badge count={getCartCount()}>
    <img
      className="bag__img"
      src={getCartCount()>0 ? bag : "/emty-bag-goes-here.png"}
      alt=""
      onClick={user ? handleOpenBag : handleDynamicLink}
      onMouseOver={() => setbag(hoverbag)}
      onMouseOut={() => setbag(cart)}
    />
</Badge>
```